# InfoPath Pop-Up Window

Tags: infopath, ajax

I have a custom Web Part that displays information in an ASP.NET ListView.  Upon clicking an item, I need to pop up an InfoPath form via AJAX to edit the item without leaving the page.

The functionality I am going for is the same as if you click "Edit" on an item in a SharePoint List.  The background fades out and the InfoPath form is shown as a modal pop-up.  I know how to achieve the background fading, but I am running into a dead end with trying to host an InfoPath form outside of the standard InfoPath web part.

Does anyone have any experience with hosting an IP form without using the pre-made webpart (or XmlFormView, which seems to just be another web part), or know where any information can be found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have an iframe which loads the FormService.aspx file pointing to your form, with the relavent querystring parms to display the form in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Could you accomplish the functionality that you need using a DVWP and enabling the inline edit functionality?